# sequlize filled user table by null values, what is the issue

Tags: sequelize.js

Hi im developing a graphql mutation to create a user record. feels everything is fine , but only null values are entered in the database. Don't know what went wrong. how to make this code working. Please help

```
createUser:(root,args,context,info) =>{    
db.user.create({
firstName: args.firstName,                                               
middleName: args.middleName,
lastName:args.lastName,                                                    
dob:args.dob,  
})
.then(result => {
console.log(`New user has been created.`);
});
```

},

user table will look like

```
        module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
            return sequelize.define('users', {
                id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
                },       
                firstName: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,  field : "firstname" 
                },
                lastName: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING, field : "lastname" 
                },
                middleName: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,  field : "middlename"   
                },
                dob: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,     
                },  
            }, {         
                tableName: 'user',
                timestamps: false
            });
        };
```

my schema will look like

```
createUser( input:UserInput ):User

type User{
id:ID
firstName
lastName
middleName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`createUser` mutation receive a `UserInput` : `createUser(input: UserInput ): User`,
you can access the input with `args.input`. I suppose the `UserInput` definition is

```
input UserInput{
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  middleName: String
  dob: String
}
```

Then in `createUser`

```
createUser: (root, args, context, info) => {
    const input = args.input;
    db.user.create({
        firstName: input.firstName,
        middleName: input.middleName,
        lastName: input.lastName,
        dob: input.dob,
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(`New user has been created.`);
    });
}
```